# Spring Data custom base repository elasticsearchrepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've gone through multiple stack overflow questions and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository

Here's my implementation

The config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class, basePackages = "com.will.repository")
public class ElasticsearchConfig {
     ...elasticsearch config
}
```

The base interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends ElasticsearchRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S saveAndEmit(S entity);
}
```

The base implementation

```
public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends AbstractElasticsearchRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public MyRepositoryImpl(ElasticsearchEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata, ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations) {
        super(metadata, elasticsearchOperations);
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S saveAndEmit(S entity) {
        S savedEntity = super.save(entity);
        publisher.publishEvent(new PostSaveEvent<>(savedEntity));
        return savedEntity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String stringIdRepresentation(ID id) {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
}
```

The entity specific interface

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends MyRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type MyEntity!
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myEntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type MyEntity!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type MyEntity!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:356) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:267) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchPartQuery.<init>(ElasticsearchPartQuery.java:46) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory$ElasticsearchQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:123) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please?

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski okay, I added the full stack trace

Comment: why don't you use this :   spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch and  spring-boot-starter-data-rest , with data rest you just need this on your repository class  @RepositoryRestResource